# How can I force trolls to drop their inventory before I kick or ban them?

Tags: dont-starve-together

Don't Starve Together is fun, but public servers attract trolls once in a while.
Someone dies, they steal that player's stuff, and won't give it back.

I'm an admin on a server. I can easily ban them, but the stolen stuff disappears with them. I can rollback, but that's a bit overkill (10 players lose a day's work because of one troll).

I can execute basic console commands: `c_give`, `c_spawn`, `c_move`, `c_save`, `c_rollback`, `c_regenerateworld`, but can't install mods.

**What command(s) can I execute to force trolls to drop their inventory (killing them is acceptable), before I kick/ban them?**

Comment: You should kill, revive, let him think it's a joke, kill, revive... and the loop goes on and on.

Comment: And despawn him, too. That's fun. (deletes items, though) `c_despawn(AllPlayers[number])`

Comment: If the game is designed this way…

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a full list of the commands [on the wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Console/Don't_Starve_Together_Commands).

I think this one would to the job (killing him, hence dropping the precious items) : `AllPlayers[number]:PushEvent('death')`

`number` being, of course, the identifier of the troll, which you can determine from `c_listallplayers()`.

Comment: I think this is supposed to be the correct answer, but the `c_listallplayers` acts weirdly for me. I run it, it gives me a number for each player, I kill player 2 and someone else dies. As a workaround, maybe there is a way to store player2 in a variable and check who I have? I tried using a `c_move`, but that's a bit intrusive. A way to print their name or omething would be nice.

Comment: Weird indeed. The numbers given by the command should be the same as those in the scoreboard, are they ?

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn something to kill him, grab all the stuff and then ban him. You get the stuff, the trolls get out of your server.

I am not really good with admin tools for Don't Starve Together though, so I can't post any commands for you, but just a simple idea.

Comment: I've tried that before, but spawning something that kills him sometimes is a risk for the others too. Once I spawned 20 pigs because the troll was a webber, that was fun - but if he had been smart, he could have just disconnected and left with all the stuff.